# XmlWriter: is calling Close() required if using a using block?

Tags: c#

Is it sufficient to create an XmlWriter with a using block (with no call to Close()) or is it better to use a try/finally block and call Close() in finally?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The using block is a shortcut for a try/finally block with a call to Dispose() on any object that implements IDisposable.

In the case of streams and stream writers, Dispose() generally calls Close() manually.  Using reflector, here's the Dispose method of XmlWriter:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.WriteState != WriteState.Closed)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

So the short answer is yes, the `using` block will handle closing the XmlWriter for you.

Comment: And this is indeed the code I was just looking at. All it does is call `Close`.

Answer (score 3):

No, calling it separately is not required. That's exactly what the using block is for.

When execution exits the using block, the XmlWriter is disposed, and on the inside, `XmlWriter.Dispose` calls `XmlWriter.Close`.

Answer (score 3):

But...
Reflector on the XmltTextWriter.Close() show :

if(this.closeOutput)
{
this.stream.Close();
}
this.Stream = null;

the closeOutput flag is set to settings.CloseOutput, which can be false.

Are you sure the handler is free when using "using" expression on the XmlTextWriter ?

Comment: Now it shows empty virtual function:  public virtual void Close() {}